# How to find $on for an event broadcast in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to **angularjs** ( 1.7.x) , I was debugging a code which had one event fired using **$broadcast**, is there an easy way or any practice which I can follow to find which function was executed using **$on** in chrome devtools ?

Comment: How about call stack (Under Sources) in Dev tool ? M not sure. Try and let me know if it helped

Comment: I just know event was broadcasted.. I don't know where listener was defined